# "Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference" AngularJS Sharepoint 2013 IE9 Sharepoint web part grouped

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, internet-explorer-9

i get this browser error "Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference" when using AnguarJS with IE9 and Sharepoint 2013 on-prem and having a sharepoint web part grouped by any of the columns. IE10/11 and Chrome doesn't seem to have a problem.

I can fix the error by declaring the  ng-app="myApp"  in the DIV of the control that i am creating. But i have a few controls on the page so i need to declare this in the main "html" element ideally. 
`<html  ng-app="myApp">` but every time i move the ng-app to a higher level it comes up with that error. Even when i move it to the "PlaceHolderMain" it still seems to error. This can be reproduced on an OOTB sharepoint page/masterpage.

Just place this in the "head"

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('myApp', []);

        </script>
```

then in the html element it should look somthing like

```
<html  ng-app="myApp" class="fluid" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
```

You don't even need an angular control on the page to cause this error, just put a sharepoint web part grouped by a column on a page.

Then when you go into IE9 developer toolbar you should get

```
{description: "Unable to g...", message: "Unable to g...", name: "TypeError", number: -2146823281}

"Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference"
```

The problem has somthing to do with the sharepiont webpart sitting inside the ng-app, as there is not problem when the ng-app is declared in a div on the page with no sharepoint grouped webpart inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the Sharepoint's Main Content (where the web parts are located) to ignore all angularJs commands in IE. But all your angular code need to be outside of the main content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (msieversion() != false && msieversion() != 'otherbrowser') {
    $("#ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv").attr("ng-non-bindable","");
}

function msieversion() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)));
    else // If another browser, return 0
        return 'otherbrowser';
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: John at the moment this error comes up without any angular code except the " angular.module('myApp', []);" above.

Answer (score 0):

It's better use this

```
if (msieversion() != false && msieversion() != 'otherbrowser') {
   $("[id^='WebPartWP'").attr("ng-non-bindable","");
}
```

It will match every sharepoint webpart